# How to stop SSH disconnect after a a certain amount of time

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I connect to my Ubuntu 14.04 VPS using putty.  The connection used to just stay alive indefinitely.  Now though I seem to be getting a disconnect after a certain amount of time.

I have done some Google searches but can't find something to solve my issue.

My /etc/ssh/sshd_config file has "TCPKeepAlive yes" set up in it.  Is there some other setting I need?

The only changes I have made recently are that Installed and setup fail2ban.

Comment: Add `ClientAliveInterval 120` to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and then check..

Comment: Thanks, I added it to my /etc/ssh/sshd_config and then typed "sudo service ssh restart".  We will see how it goes now and if I get any disconnects.

Comment: I have never been able to solve this issue myself, having tried adding the keep alive intervals suggested, using screen, whatever. I have had this issue in different computers connected to different networks, with different servers. Good luck.

Comment: Do you get any error message on disconnection? Like "broken pipe" or something else?

Comment: @EricCarvalho For me, the error is just something like "Network Error: Software caused connection abort".  It happens in both Putty and WinSCP

Comment: The connection closes even while you're "using" it (typing, etc.)? Or does it close after some time of **inactivity**?

Comment: @EricCarvalho good point!  It only does this after a period of inactivity. Which is what makes me think it is some kind of purposeful timeout.

Comment: Check the TMOUT variable: `echo $TMOUT`. If it is set, bash will close after inactive for the number of seconds in TMOUT.

Comment: Hum...that is interesting...when I try "echo $TMOUT" it echos back nothing.

Comment: Hum...this may actually be a putty setting I need to manipulate.  Found this:  http://staff.ask.sydney.edu.au/app/answers/detail/a_id/614/~/how-do-i-configure-my-putty-client-to-not-time-out-due-to-inactivity%3F

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you deleted ~/.ssh/config by accident. Run in the remote system:

`sudo nano ~/.ssh/config`

And insert the following:

```
Host *

  ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Then type:

`sudo service ssh restart`

What it does is to tell the server that you are alive every 60 seconds.

Comment: If the network is aggressively disconnecting, you may need to set 60 to a lower number.

Comment: This is for the client, not the server

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my maybe dump answer: in your post you wrote that you made a change by setting up fail2ban.

Did you configure a jail for sshd?

If it is the case please try out if stopping the fail2ban server helps.